# phpThumb plugin and database images' querystrings

Tags: php, query-string, phpthumb

i'm new to the phpthumb plugin and searched stackoverflow for similar questions without success

a standard phpthumb request should be like this

```
<img src="phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src=../RANDOM-IMAGE.gif&w=100&q=100" />
```

What if my image is coming from a mysql db and its url is a querystring?

```
<img src="http://www.somewebsite.com/gallery.php?img=PARAM1&id=PARAM2" />')
```

How can i generate thumbnails with phpthumb plugin with url like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this way

```
$imageTempURL=rawurlencode("http://www.somewebsite.com/gallery.php?img=imageID");


echo('<img src="phpthumb/phpThumb.php?src='.$imageTempURL);
```